# Entity Framework model first: create UNIQUE constraint programmatically

Tags: entity-framework, unique-constraint, ef-model-first

I am trying to add a UNIQUE constraint to the "Username" property of my "UserAccount" entity/class. With code-first, that would be no problem, but for model-first, I can't find anything on how to achieve that. 
The designer does not support this feature. I cannot use annotations because the entity classes are auto-generated. I cannot use Fluent API because the *OnModelCreating()* method is not called in model-first and thus I have no *DbModelBuilder* instance. 
The only thing I can think of is executing some kind of manual SQL statement at application start that creates the UNIQUE constraint, which kind of defeats the purpose of EF. 
Here is my current DbContext class:

```
 public partial class UserAccountsModelContainer : DbContext
 {
    public UserAccountsModelContainer()
        : base("name=UserAccountsModelContainer")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

I won't even bother to post the *UserAccount* class since it's auto-generated and shouldn't be modified (I know that the DbContext is also auto-generated, but modifying it is possible). 
Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: Lets face it... model first is dying in favor of code first. If you are really lucky, someone will come around with a more or less working solution, but think hard whether you can possibly move away from model first for your project.

Comment: Already started with that ;) 
I just can't believe that such a simple task was never integrated in model-first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will recommend you to switch to Entity Framework Code First, too. It gives you much more controll about every thing that is possible with EF.

I never used it before, but I know `Model Conventions`. They are applicable to the model configuration. Maybe it will be an approach to set up a convention for a defined model type/property that should be configured as unique constraint.

Based on the following it should be possible to modify the set up of model first on creating database.

> Model Conventions are based on the underlying model metadata. There
>   are conventions for both CSDL and SSDL. Create a class that implements
>   IConceptualModelConvention from CSDL conventions and implement
>   IStoreModelConvention for SSDL convention.

Source: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/custom-conventions-codefirst.aspx

> There are two types of model conventions, Conceptual (C-Space) and
>   Store (S-Space). This distinction indicates where in the pipeline a
>   convention is executed. A C-Space convention is applied to the model
>   that the application builds, whereas an S-Space convention is applied
>   to the version of the model.

Source: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions

Some more example implementations incl. explainations are findabe on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469439(v=vs.113).aspx). I guess they are very helpful for your case.

One example from MSDN:

```
public class DiscriminatorRenamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>  
{  
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)  
    {            
        if (property.Name == "Discriminator")  
        {  
            property.Name = "EntityType";  
        }  
    }  
}
```

It will rename the column *Discriminator* into *EntityType*. It is a very simple example but you could modify it to solve your problem to:

```
public class ModelBasedConvention : IConceptualModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        if (property.Name == "Username"
            && property.DeclaringType.GetType() == typeof(UserAccount))
        {
            property.AddAnnotation("UniqueKey", property);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. In light of the complexity of achieving such a simple task, I decided to swtich to code-first though (based on grek40's answer and my own testing).